# is Parasurama Kund a holy place and is this the correct location?

Tags: ramayana, india, parashurama, pilgrimage

There is a place called [Parsuram Kund](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Parsuram+Kund/@27.6627125,94.8890078,9z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1siskcon+china!3m4!1s0x373e792a44f70e97:0x22beb6e355c9dcd3!8m2!3d27.8748366!4d96.3642436) and I wonder if it has something to do with [Lord Parasurama](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29863/3294).

This place is on the Brahmaputra River, as you can see on the picture below.

Click on the image for more accurate map from Google maps.

Is there where Lord Parasurama resided\resides?

[[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUwqk.png)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Parsuram+Kund/@27.6627125,94.8890078,9z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1siskcon+china!3m4!1s0x373e792a44f70e97:0x22beb6e355c9dcd3!8m2!3d27.8748366!4d96.3642436)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when Lord Parashurama killed his mother with an axe on the orders of his father, the axe got stuck to his hand as he had committed a heinous crime by killing his mother. So, in order to wash away his sin, he came to Lohit river in Arunachal Pradesh. As soon as he put his hand inside the pristine waters of the river, the axe got detached from his hand. Since then, the site has been a significant place of worship and is known as Parshuram Kund.

So obviously it is Holy place..

Comment: Answer appears copied from https://www.nativeplanet.com/travel-guide/parshuram-kund-where-lord-parashurama-expiated-after-beheading-his-mother-004933.html without attribution.

Comment: when answer is accepted and most importantly when the question asker's doubts are clear the answers doesn't matter whether they are copied or not

Comment: From SE guidelines on [How to reference material written by others](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing): "Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your answer being down-voted or deleted."